# Blender 3D to 2D Transformation giving wrong bounding box coordinates

Tags: python, mesh, 3d-view, vertices, mathematics

Hello fellow stack overflowers, I was trying to use some 6D Pose Estimation algorithm with a custom dataset. Its going pretty good but I need to save the labels aka the 2d coordinates of the bounding box showed in the picture. Unfortunaly it doesnt match the ground truth data, probably Im doing something wrong in my code.

First of all im trying to recreate this 6D Pose Estimation Algorithm: https://github.com/Microsoft/singleshotpose

I generate an object in blender, position its centroid at (0,0,0) and then take a picture of it. The idea is to use a for loop to easily generate 1000 pictures so i can train the model well. Here is the code to get the 2d bounding box

```
scene = bpy.context.scene
brick = bpy.data.objects['brick']
bb_vertices = [Vector(v) for v in brick.bound_box]
mat = brick.matrix_world
world_bb_vertices = [mat @ v for v in bb_vertices]
co_2d = [world_to_camera_view(scene, scene.camera, v) for v in world_bb_vertices]
co_2d_new = np.delete(co_2d, 2, 1)
co_2d_final = np.reshape(co_2d_new, -1)

#print(co_2d_final)
# [0.44425908 0.54335487 0.3063629  0.47222671 0.29777738 0.6361047
# 0.44198048 0.69735122 0.71110761 0.3768487  0.57061917 0.27459577
# 0.57443786 0.46377245 0.7214548  0.55333525]
```

The last two steps are there to reshape it, as i get the (x,y,z) coordinates but the z coordinate is not needed. When I use opencv to picture the labels I get this :

[image: Picture of the new drawn bounding box]

As u can see, the dots dont resemble the bounding box coordinates but it looks kinda familiar. I would be really grateful if someone could help me! Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like your Y axis in opencv raises down, while in Blender it raises up, hence the dots are flipped.

Comment: Thanks @MarkusvonBroady your answer is correct. When I use (1 - y_value) I get the correct bounding box. 
Is there any way to change this in blender? I am trying to generate over 1000 images and labels in blender. Changing the y-axis in blender would defintilely make it way easier

Comment: I don't think you can change the axis in Blender, but as you noticed, flipping is mathematically trivial.